# AIX 0403-006 Execute permission denied

Tags: aix

I am using a shell script on AIX.
I have given the execution permission using chmod
Still,I am getting the following error:

> ksh: ./getcwd.exe: 0403-006 Execute permission denied.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the program you are trying to run is getcwd.exe, run the file command on it.

> file getcwd.exe

This will give you and idea of what type of file it is.
  * If the output says RISC System/6000 or 64-bit XCOFF executable, it is likely compiled for AIX.
  *  If it says DOS or ELF-386 executable, it will not run on AIX.  It was compiled to run on Intel x86 compatible processors.
  *  If it says shell executable or commands text, it should run, but you may need to specify the shell interpreter to run it with.  For example:

> ksh getcwd.exe

In your case, it looks like you may be running a script which calls getcwd.exe.  In this case, the script could be runnable (executable), but getcwd.exe may not have the executable bits set.  You would also have to chmod getcwd.exe (assuming it is a program that could normally run on AIX).S

Answer (score 4):

Use **ls -l** to list the permissions for your files in the directory

If the file concerned does not have x (execute) you need to add it

**chmod a+x myfile.sh**

Answer (score 3):

Hmm AIX System dont support exe(Executable) files.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the script was written for another platform like windows on x86. 
AIX doesn't use extensions like .EXE to identify executable files but Windows does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `unrar` the `.exe` file. Each `exe` has one or more `rar` files associated with it. Once you run `unrar x filename.exe` it will unpack the associated exe and rar files into a directory.